# Are there blind Starcraft players?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft

I've read that there are blind people who can play Starcraft competently. This seems like it would be impossible to me.

Is it possible to play Starcraft if you are blind? How would this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Most famously, a player played against SlayerS BoxeR in a showmatch in Brood War at the Blizzard World Wide Invitational tourney in January of 2004. Boxer was blindfolded for the first three minutes, after which he played normally.

The player's name was Min Seok and he played Zerg. I'm not sure if there are other players. He utilized the game sounds and the keyboard instead of the mouse to move around. You can find a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3h9TiHeoN3o) and some community commentary from TeamLiquid [here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/brood-war/10490-boxer-vs-blind-bw-player).

Comment: It might be worth adding if he can actually beat somewhat decent people (without them being blindfolded, even partial game). I can play any game blindfolded, but I'd lose hard.

Comment: I would not count "the first three minutes" as playing competently.. is there any sources of a proper game being played in this way?

Comment: @Timelord64 to be fair i'd say most starcraft players could do quite fine blindfolded for the first 3 minutes, unless they're cheesed.

Comment: @Timelord64 One player was blindfolded for the first three minutes; the other (Min Seok) was actually blind. Presumably, blindfolding SlayerS BoxeR was supposed to level the playing field to some extent.